# rmic error: class btc5.Hello not found

Tags: rmi

[Click here to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIPMn.png)

I have a problem like the picture attached, when I complied file remote class by "rmic remoteclass", It  can't auto create 2 file stub.class and skeleton.class.

Comment: You can copy paste the error stack here.  And do format the question with more details.

Comment: You *must* copy/paste the error here. And no pictures of text please, just the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

> It can't auto create 2 file stub.class and skeleton.class.

It doesn't do that. It creates *one* class, in this case `btc5.Hello_stub`. `rmic` hasn't created skeletons by default for fifteen if not twenty years.

```
class btc5.Hello not found
```

You haven't compiled it, or you aren't running the command from the directory containing `btc5`.